# Years display in Python from a age and print every year since birth

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, programmers-notepad

I want to create a code in Python that asks the user for their age and displays on the screen every year since birth, separated by commas. Using `for`.

Like this example:

> How old are you?: 37
> 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, ... 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022

Please help me.

Thank you :)

Comment: I would start with a simple `for` loop in python, and go from there.

Comment: `print(', '.join(str(y) for y in range(2022 - int(input("How old are you?: ")), 2023)))`

Comment: @Samwise this has the potential to give a wrong answer, for example if someone is born in November/December of some year. My birthday was earlier this year, so actually this doesn't affect me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "give me ur codez"

Comment: @Claudia editing the verbiage of the question doesn't change the fact that you don't have any code to start with.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You try maybe below code

```
age = input("How old are you? \n")
year = 2022-int(age)

for x in range(year, 2023):
  print("{},".format(x))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from datetime import date 
age = input("what is your age : ")
age = int(age)
out = ""
current_year = date.today().year
birth_year = current_year - age
for i in range(birth_year, current_year+ 1):
    out = out + str(i) + ", "

print(out)
```